# Please remove the "temperance" chat room from this site's admin page

Tags: bug

The admin page at https://apple.stackexchange.com/admin/dashboard will occasionally list the [Temperance](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4083) chat room which apparently is for religious moderation.

Please remove that as it doesn't concern moderation of this site.

Comment: p.s. or if it really, really has to be included - make sure our site's mod chat room is pinned to the top above off-site mod chat rooms.